# Is a Markovian chain irreducible when one state does not have a recursive path?

Tags: markov-chains

Let be the following homogeneous Markovian chain with three state:

\begin{pmatrix}
   1/2 & 1/4 & 1/4 \\
   2/3 & 0 & 1/3\\
   3/5 & 1/5 & 1/5 
\end{pmatrix}

**Is this Markovian chain irreducible?**

> From wikipedia:
>
> A Markov chain is said to be irreducible if its state space is a
>   single communicating class; in other words, if it is possible to get
>   to any state from any state.

But here, **there is no recursive path from 2 to 2, my answer would be no, but is it true?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is irreducible by the wiki definition. You can go 2 -> 1 -> 2.